# Access @Model when @Model is a Task

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

How am I supposed to use a @Model thats a Task?

**Razor:**

```
@model Task<AreBuraas.Core.v1.Models.Category>

<article class="panel panel-primary">
    <section class="panel-heading">
        <h1>
            @Model.Name
        </h1>
        <h3>
            @Model.Description
        </h3>
    </section>
    <section class="panel-body">
        her kommer content!
    </section>
</article>
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Display(int id)
{
    return View(_data.GetCategory(id));
}
```

Error:

> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no
>   extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>
> ```
>             @Model.Name
> ```
>
> 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Description' and
>   no extension method 'Description' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>
> ```
>                 @Model.Description
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that.

Instead, you should `await` the task in your controller and pass its result to the view.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a thing you should focus on With a controller. The @model in razor syntax cannot be a task. Instead, this is What controller is for, and by convention it should pass the actual result to the view.

Answer (score 0):

> **Landed on this solution:**

```
public IActionResult Display(int id)
{
    var data = _data.GetCategory(id);
    var result = data.Result;

    return View(result);
}
```